# How can I change background color for Maui Webview in iOS platform

Tags: maui

In my dotnet maui app (version 8) I have a WebView and I want to change the background color to black with a handler in the iOS platform. In Android platform I can change in directly on the control like this:

```
 <WebView Grid.Row="0" x:Name="webView" HeightRequest="250" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Gray800}"></WebView>
```

But that doesn't take effect on iOS so I've tried to make it work with a handler without success.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try adding the following code in code behind,

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ModifyWebView();
}

void ModifyWebView()
{
    Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.WebViewHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping("MyCustomization", (handler, view) =>
    {

#if IOS || MACCATALYST
        handler.PlatformView.Opaque = false;
        handler.PlatformView.BackgroundColor = UIKit.UIColor.Clear;
#endif
    });
}
```

For more info, you could refer to [Customize controls with handlers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/customize?view=net-maui-8.0).

Comment: Exactly ehat I needed. Thanks!